# What is the relationship between vector fields with the same curl?

Tags: vector-fields, curl

Is there any sort of intuitive relationship between vector fields with the same curl? For example, indefinite integrals, (functions that have the same derivatives), are all related such that they are all off by a constant.

But there doesn't seem a clear cut relationship between vector fields with the same curl. For instance, in two dimensions the vector fields $\langle -y,0\rangle$ and $\langle 0,x\rangle$ both have the same two dimensional curl of $1$. But I cannot see a relationship between these two fields. Does one exist?

Comment: in dimension 2 or 3, it means the difference of the vector fields is (locally) a gradient. So your second minus first is $\langle y,x \rangle$ the gradient of $f(x,y) = xy$

Comment: @WillJagy -- It's not limited to 2D and 3D, if you use a suitable definition of curl (using the wedge product instead of the cross product).